# Is any possibilities to use ANT UI Design in Electron Desktop App Framework?

Tags: electron

I have found so many facility to use javascript, Angular, material design ui with [Electron App Framework](https://electron.atom.io/), I would like to know, is there any possibilities to use [ANT UI](https://ant.design/) for my desktop application? At-least some work around.

Comment: From the readme of ANT project at github, it seems that Electron is an officially supported  environment. here is the link  https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/#environment-support

Comment: @ParthipanNatkunam, thanks let me have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

The short answer is yes. Electron provides an entire NodeJS environment and allows you to use common Node, Javascript and React toolsets.

In fact, Electron is listed as an officially supported environment on [their Github page](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/#environment-support).

That being said, it's a very diverse library so there might be occurrences where a particular component is not supported or might need tweaking to be compatible with the Electron environment.

#### Update

The company I work for actually had to do this for a project we're working on so I can officially confirm that it works great.

Comment: Thanks, i need to try

Comment: @manny The company I work for actually had to do this for a project we're working on so I can officially confirm it works great. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @manny Make sure to accept an answer if you think it's the correct one. ;)